# How to keep the points symbol inside plot border in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting a graph with lines points in gnuplot. My points symbols are so big that it goes outside the graph border. I want the plot where points symbols (say, circles) will not go outside border of the graph.

Could anyone please help me with this.

Many thanks,

Comment: You can use `set offsets` for that

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/23301274/2604213 for an example. You can use all unit types to specify those offsets (first, second, screen, graph, char, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23180595/2604213)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried set offsets but it did not work. Actually, I have a line plotted with points. I have chosen point type circles. Because Circles are big in size some part of the circles goes outside the border. I can use gimp to remove those parts. But, I have many graphs. So, I want a way to keep the circles inside the graph border in gnuplot.

Comment: Then, please show a full, but minimal example that shows your problem.

Comment: Are you talking about the `set clip` commands ?

Comment: I am not talking about set clip command. Actually I could sow you one example. Unfortunately, I do not know  how to attach a figure in the comment here. Can you tell me how to attach a figure here.